# Trying to have three columns of data using three arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi so i am working on a program to calculate 10 students grades using arrays and methods the marks from the students have been given as seen below. the problem i am having is displaying the name average and grade in 3 columns next to each other. the current code im using to print out the arrays prints them likes this

```
 The Average is
 Average: 82.4
 Average: 81.2
 Average: 66.6
 Average: 72.2
 Average: 52.2
 Average: 59.2
 Average: 63.4
 Average: 90.0
 Average: 73.4
 Average: 68.8
 The grade is
 Grade = B
 Grade = B
 Grade = C
 Grade = C
 Grade = D
 Grade = D
 Grade = D
 Grade = A
 Grade = C
 Grade = C
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

here is the code with name marks and averages i have done any help is really appreciated

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Question2Assignment {

public static double [][] Marks;
public static char [] graded;
public static String [] Name;
public static double [] avg;

public static void main(String[] args) {

  inMarks() ;
  SNames();  

 System.out.println("The Average is"); 
 for (double number : AverageMarks(Marks))
 {

     System.out.print("Average: " + number);
     System.out.println("");
 }


 System.out.println("The grade is");
 for (char grade : Grade(graded))
  {
     System.out.print("Grade = " + grade);
     System.out.println("");

 }
} 

private static void inMarks()
{
    Marks = new double [][] {{85,83,77,91,76},{80,90,95,93,48},{78,81,11,90,73},{92,83,30,69,87},{23,45,96,38,59},{60,85,45,39,67},{77,31,52,74,83},{93,94,89,77,97},{79,85,28,93,82},{85,72,49,75,63}};
}

private static void SNames()
{
    Name = new String [] {"Jognson","Aniston","Cooper","Gupta","Blair","Clark","Kennedy","Bronson","Sunny","Smith"};
}


public static double[] AverageMarks(double[][] Marks)
{

double avg[] = new double [Marks.length];

for (int row = 0; row < Marks.length; row++){
    int sum=0;
    for (int col = 0; col < Marks[row].length; col++){
        sum += Marks[row][col];
    }
    avg[row] = 1.0*sum / Marks[row].length; // calc average

}
return avg;
 }
      public static char [] Grade(char[] Graded)
  {
 char [] graded = new char [10];
 int count = 0;
 for (double number : AverageMarks(Marks)) 
 {

     if(number <50)
     {
         graded [count] = 'F';
     count++;
     }
     else if (number <65)
     {
         graded [count]= 'D';
         count++;
     }
     else if (number <75)
     {
         graded [count] = 'C';
         count++;
     }
     else if (number <85)
     {
         graded [count] ='B';
         count++;
     }
     else   
     {
         graded [count]='A';
         count++;
     }
    }//first for loop
  return graded;
  }


   }//class end
```

Comment: You need to think about the flow of what you are doing and what you are trying to do.  What you are doing is printing all of the averages and then printing all of the grades. What you want to do is print the right avg and grade with the correct student. You need one for loop to do this and don't use the for each for loop.

Comment: its obvious it won't print them column wise ! one solution is you need to declare 2 arrays or lists and store all results in them and then use loop to print both elements in arrays.

Comment: i am not sure how to type it out in 1 for loop   using   for (double number : AverageMarks(Marks))  cause when i try add (char grade : Grade(graded)) it just doest work which is expected

Comment: @aaronyoung try to use a class with student details and methods to return the average and grade which will be much easier for you

Comment: i added them now says incompatible types: char[] cannot be converted to char and same but with the other one

Comment: Never mind  it worked i just changed them to double[] numbers = AverageMarks(Marks);
       char[] grade = Grade(graded);

Comment: I didn't do array types char[] grade and double[] number.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson , I posted the answer before seeing your post. Sorry and we both had similar thoughts.

Comment: I saw yours and deleted mine. No problem.

Comment: Since you seem to be learning how to program, you should look into programming best practices. Also, if the assignment did not call for handling the global variables the way you did, I would rethink and redo the program.

Comment: I have never seen a beginners java course ask students to handle variables globally. I think you should move your global variables into the main and then pass them to the methods.

Comment: what do u mean global variables  ?

Comment: @SedrickJefferson , I guess we should direct him towards classes and objects. Then he will get the gist of what you are trying to say

Comment: @AaronYong learn about static keyword in java and classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`double[] averageMarks = AverageMarks(Marks);
char[] grades = Grade(graded);
for (int i = 0; i<Name.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Name[i]+" "+averageMarks[i]+" "+grades[i]);
    }`
```

the above given answer points you to proper direction but gives wrong results for this case

Comment: There is changes to occur `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` so that is not able to accepted.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i<Name.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(Name[i]+" "+avg[i]+" "+graded[i]);
}
```